# macOS System files to modify Display Resolutions?

Tags: display, resolution

Duet Display can no longer set my iPad to 2732x2048 resolution. I have the exact same problem with my ASUS monitor. I was once able to use PBP mode to turn the display into portrait mode and then set both sides to 1920x2160 resolution, this is also now impossible since the tools I once used can no longer configure a specific display resolution.

So now I've picked up this old **cscreen**:
http://www.pyehouse.com/cscreen/

I've disabled system integrity protection on my MacBook Pro, but even **cscreen** will not allow it. **cscreen** will only allow me to pick from these specific options:

```
DisplayID  Index     Depth     Width     Height  Refresh
 4280c02       1        32      2880       1800     0
 4280c02       2        32      1440        900     0
 4280c02       3        32      3360       2100     0
 4280c02       4        32      2560       1600     0
 4280c02       5        32      2048       1280     0
 4280c02       6        32      1650       1050     0
 4280c02       7        32      1280        800     0
 4280c02       8        32      1152        720     0
 4280c02       9        32      1024        768     0
 4280c02      10        32       840        524     0
 4280c02      11        32       800        600     0
 4280c02      12        32       640        480     0
DisplayID  Index     Depth     Width     Height  Refresh
1b400045       1        32      1360        768    60
1b400045       2        32      1024        768    60
1b400045       3        32      1280        720    60
1b400045       4        32       720        480    60
1b400045       5        32       640        480    60
1b400045       6        32       800        600    60
1b400045       7        32      1024        578    60
DisplayID  Index     Depth     Width     Height  Refresh
  3f003d       1        32       800        600    60
  3f003d       2        32      1024        768    60
  3f003d       3        32      1280        720    60
  3f003d       4        32      1280       1024    60
  3f003d       5        32      1440        900    60
  3f003d       6        32      1680       1050    60
  3f003d       7        32      1920       1080    60
```

My iPad has the id `3f003d` and it will now ONLY be set to those resolutions.

I tried the command:
`./cscreen -i 3f003d -s 3f003d -x 2732 -y 2048`
and no luck.

Does anyone know where I could find the system files where these very specific values are coming from?

I'm well aware of the risks, so I'll test it on an old MacBook I don't use anymore or maybe take a stab at doing in in a VMWare Fusion vm. I'm more than willing to take the risk because I hate to have this expensive piece of  hardware sitting around doing nothing while I'm on the go using my laptop.

Comment: I'm not sure if these will help, but 1) Retina Display Monitor http://avi.alkalay.net/software/RDM/  2) https://github.com/univ-of-utah-marriott-library-apple/display_manager and 3) SwitchResX http://www.madrau.com/srx_download/download.html would be the 3 places I'd start

Comment: Thanks, when I use SwitchResX and RDM at the same time, it looks like SwitchResX will then allow me to set a custom resolution. However, Duet Display will crash unfortunately when I try to go past 1080p : /